# ADF connectivity with SAP HANA - SSL

Tags: ssl, azure-data-factory, hana

I'm working on a project to get data from SAP HANA tables using Azure Data Factory, and I don't know if SSL certificates are supported by the SAP HANA connector, I would like to know if SAP HANA supports SSL certificates.
Note: according to the Azure documentation there's no info on that.

This is my reference info: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/Azure-DataFactory/main/whitepaper/SAP%20Data%20Integration%20using%20Azure%20Data%20Factory.pdf

but from 2020

Answer (score 0):

SAP HANA supports network encryption with SSL.
Details vary if you connect to HANA Cloud (managed service) or HANA running in a vm or an appliance.
In the first case, SSL is mandatory, in the second, it is optional [unless configured otherwise](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/b3ee5778bc2e4a089d3299b82ec762a7/dbd3d887bb571014bf05ca887f897b99.html).

The ADF SAP HANA Connector relies on the HANA ODBC driver. SSL and other connection settings are set in the ODBC data source.

FYI, if you intend to connect at the database level, you should make  sure there is a valid license to do so, even if it's technically possible.